# No module named 'line_profiler'

Tags: python, line-profiler

I am trying to do line profile and memory profile in python. 
I imported line_profiler by 
from line_profiler import LineProfiler
when I run my code, I get the error message:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'line_profiler'

when I try to install it using pip install:

```
py -m pip install line_profiler
```

everything is good, but at the end it gives something in red:

> C:\Users\asmobari>py -m pip install line_profiler Collecting
>   line_profiler   Using cached
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/14/fc/ecf4e238bb601ff829068e5a72cd1bd67b0ee0ae379db172eb6a0779c6b6/line_profiler-2.1.2.tar.gz
>   Requirement already satisfied: IPython>=0.13 in
>   c:\users\asmobari\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages
>   (from line_profiler) (7.0.1) Requirement already satisfied:
>   traitlets>=4.2 in
>   c:\users\asmobari\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages
>   (from IPython>=0.13->line_profiler) (4.3.2) Requirement already
>   satisfied: simplegeneric>0.8 in
>   c:\users\asmobari\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages
>   (from IPython>=0.13->line_profiler) (0.8.1) Requirement already
>   satisfied: backcall in
>   c:\users\asmobari\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages
>   (from IPython>=0.13->line_profiler) (0.1.0) Requirement already
>   satisfied: decorator in
>   c:\users\asmobari\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages
>   (from IPython>=0.13->line_profiler) (4.3.0) Requirement already
>   satisfied: pickleshare in
>   c:\users\asmobari\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages
>   (from IPython>=0.13->line_profiler) (0.7.5) Requirement already
>   satisfied: jedi>=0.10 in
>   c:\users\asmobari\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages
>   (from IPython>=0.13->line_profiler) (0.13.1) Requirement already
>   satisfied: pygments in
>   c:\users\asmobari\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages
>   (from IPython>=0.13->line_profiler) (2.2.0) Requirement already
>   satisfied: colorama; sys_platform == "win32" in
>   c:\users\asmobari\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages
>   (from IPython>=0.13->line_profiler) (0.4.0) Requirement already
>   satisfied: prompt-toolkit<2.1.0,>=2.0.0 in
>   c:\users\asmobari\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages
>   (from IPython>=0.13->line_profiler) (2.0.6) Requirement already
>   satisfied: setuptools>=18.5 in
>   c:\users\asmobari\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages
>   (from IPython>=0.13->line_profiler) (39.0.1) Requirement already
>   satisfied: ipython-genutils in
>   c:\users\asmobari\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages
>   (from traitlets>=4.2->IPython>=0.13->line_profiler) (0.2.0)
>   Requirement already satisfied: six in
>   c:\users\asmobari\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages
>   (from traitlets>=4.2->IPython>=0.13->line_profiler) (1.11.0)
>   Requirement already satisfied: parso>=0.3.0 in
>   c:\users\asmobari\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages
>   (from jedi>=0.10->IPython>=0.13->line_profiler) (0.3.1) Requirement
>   already satisfied: wcwidth in
>   c:\users\asmobari\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages
>   (from prompt-toolkit<2.1.0,>=2.0.0->IPython>=0.13->line_profiler)
>   (0.1.7) Installing collected packages: line-profiler   Running
>   setup.py install for line-profiler ... error
>       Complete output from command C:\Users\asmobari\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe -u
>   -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\asmobari\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2w13a4ux\line-profiler\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record C:\Users\asmobari\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-h8dq1h7x\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
>       running install
>       running build
>       running build_py
>       creating build
>       creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
>       copying line_profiler.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
>       copying kernprof.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
>       copying line_profiler_py35.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
>       running build_ext
>       skipping '_line_profiler.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
>       building '_line_profiler' extension
>       creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
>       creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
>       C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe
>   /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD
>   -IC:\Users\asmobari\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include -IC:\Users\asmobari\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include"
>   "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt"
>   "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\shared"
>   "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\um"
>   "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\winrt"
>   "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\cppwinrt" /Tc_line_profiler.c
>   /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release_line_profiler.obj
>       _line_profiler.c
>       _line_profiler.c(7890): error C2039: 'exc_type': is not a member of '_ts'
>       c:\users\asmobari\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pystate.h(209):
>   note: see declaration of '_ts'
>       _line_profiler.c(7891): error C2039: 'exc_value': is not a member of '_ts'
>       c:\users\asmobari\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pystate.h(209):
>   note: see declaration of '_ts'
>       _line_profiler.c(7892): error C2039: 'exc_traceback': is not a member of '_ts'
>       c:\users\asmobari\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pystate.h(209):
>   note: see declaration of '_ts'
>       _line_profiler.c(7899): error C2039: 'exc_type': is not a member of '_ts'
>       c:\users\asmobari\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pystate.h(209):
>   note: see declaration of '_ts'
>       _line_profiler.c(7900): error C2039: 'exc_value': is not a member of '_ts'
>       c:\users\asmobari\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pystate.h(209):
>   note: see declaration of '_ts'
>       _line_profiler.c(7901): error C2039: 'exc_traceback': is not a member of '_ts'
>       c:\users\asmobari\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pystate.h(209):
>   note: see declaration of '_ts'
>       _line_profiler.c(7902): error C2039: 'exc_type': is not a member of '_ts'
>       c:\users\asmobari\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pystate.h(209):
>   note: see declaration of '_ts'
>       _line_profiler.c(7903): error C2039: 'exc_value': is not a member of '_ts'
>       c:\users\asmobari\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pystate.h(209):
>   note: see declaration of '_ts'
>       _line_profiler.c(7904): error C2039: 'exc_traceback': is not a member of '_ts'
>       c:\users\asmobari\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pystate.h(209):
>   note: see declaration of '_ts'
>       _line_profiler.c(7959): error C2039: 'exc_type': is not a member of '_ts'
>       c:\users\asmobari\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pystate.h(209):
>   note: see declaration of '_ts'
>       _line_profiler.c(7960): error C2039: 'exc_value': is not a member of '_ts'
>       c:\users\asmobari\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pystate.h(209):
>   note: see declaration of '_ts'
>       _line_profiler.c(7961): error C2039: 'exc_traceback': is not a member of '_ts'
>       c:\users\asmobari\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pystate.h(209):
>   note: see declaration of '_ts'
>       _line_profiler.c(7962): error C2039: 'exc_type': is not a member of '_ts'
>       c:\users\asmobari\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pystate.h(209):
>   note: see declaration of '_ts'
>       _line_profiler.c(7963): error C2039: 'exc_value': is not a member of '_ts'
>       c:\users\asmobari\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pystate.h(209):
>   note: see declaration of '_ts'
>       _line_profiler.c(7964): error C2039: 'exc_traceback': is not a member of '_ts'
>       c:\users\asmobari\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pystate.h(209):
>   note: see declaration of '_ts'
>
> ```
> error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.15.26726\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe'
> ```
>
> failed with exit status 2
>
> ```
> ---------------------------------------- Command "C:\Users\asmobari\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
> ```
>
> -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\asmobari\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2w13a4ux\line-profiler\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record C:\Users\asmobari\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-h8dq1h7x\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in
>   C:\Users\asmobari\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2w13a4ux\line-profiler\

I wonder if somebody can hlep me solve this or if anyone knows a way other than  from line_profiler import LineProfiler and import line_profiler to import line_profiler

Comment: it's `pip install line-profiler` (https://pypi.org/project/line-profiler/) not `pip install line_profiler`.

Answer (score 2):

You can install a prebuilt binary from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#line_profiler)